# How to change tab order or modify tab page collection in a winform form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

So here is my scenario. I have a C# Winform application with a form that has 3 buttons.

```
Button A; //Default tabindex == 0
Button B; //Default tabindex == 1
Button C; //Default tabindex == 2
```

I programmatically create and add 3 more buttons to the form: D, E, and F. I then try the following

```
D.TabIndex = 1;
E.TabIndex = 2;
F.TabIndex = 3;
B.TabIndex = 4;
C.TabIndex = 5;
```

When I tab, it SHOULD go

```
A -> D -> E -> F -> B -> C
```

The way it actually goes, when I run the application and tab through the controls, is

```
A -> B -> C -> (some combination of D -> E -> F in whatever order I make them in)
```

I've googled the issue and keep coming up with answers that say things along the lines of "Just modify the form's tab page collection! Easy peasy!" but I can't actually find examples of how this is done. I've looked at the form's various methods and properties, but I didn't see any property that looked remotely close to being the tab page collection.

So here I am. Does anyone know of a way to do this so that the buttons go A -> D -> E -> F -> B -> C when I add D, E and F programmatically at run time?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any group controls on the form? that could cause the tab order to break.

Comment: Something's not clear to me here: do you have a problem with proper tab order or with matching TabControl pages to an actual button?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing the words TabIndex with TabControls and TabPages, etc.  The TabIndex is the order in which controls get the focus when the user clicks on the Tab key on the keyboard.

To insert your new buttons would require you to reindex the existing controls in the parent container.

A working example (assuming you have buttons A, B, C already on your form):

```
int tabIndex = 1;
foreach (string s in new string[] { "D", "E", "F" }) {
  Button b = new Button();
  b.Text = s;
  foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    if (c.TabIndex >= tabIndex) {
      c.TabIndex++;
    }
  }
  b.Location = new Point(16, tabIndex * b.Height + 4);
  b.TabIndex = tabIndex++;
  this.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Comment: b.TabIndex = this.Controls.OfType<Control>.Max(c => c.TabIndex+1);

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem could be when you create the buttons programatically.

When you create the buttons programatically, all the others controls that you already have in your form has their own `TabIndex`, then if you change the button `TabIndex` to 2, maybe another control already share the index 2, and that´s why it doesn´t work properly.

A possible solution, when you build your form, try to don´t use numbers that you will use when you create your buttons programatically ;)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Tab order traverses the tree of controls, and you can control the order among peers under the same parent node with the `TabIndex` value.  I suspect that the problem could be that the new controls are being added within an enclosing parent group and not as peers to the original button controls.  The enclosing group has its own TabIndex which defines its order relative to its own peers (the original buttons) and was put last by default.  If that's the case, the new buttons will always be last as a group no matter what you set their individual `TabIndex` values to.

Make sure the enclosing group has `TabIndex = 1` (with B moved to 2, etc) and the controls within it should then all be hit between A and B in the overall tab order.  You should be able to do this in the designer (also, use the Document Outline window to help see the tree structure of controls on the form).  Note that TabIndex applies only among peers of the same parent Control, so D, E, and F, presumably get their own TabIndex values of 0, 1, and 2.

Or, if there is no enclosing group (if the problem is that it won't let you dynamically change the tab order of the original buttons) you might be able to add a group at that spot in the tab order in the original layout and then add the dynamic buttons within that.  Of course, that depends on whether your layout is amenable to such grouping for the dynamic buttons.